# How can I make my button do something when clicked?

Tags: libgdx, android-studio

I'm trying to create a game with libGDX in Android Studio, and I am struggling with my code to add a command to the program to do something when I press the button.

I have added an `ImageButton`, but now I struggle to get it to do something when I click on it.

Here's my code:

```
 bplay.addListener( new ClickListener(){
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
            batch.begin();
            batch.draw( splash, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() );
            batch.end();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey, what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw stuff in the rendering loop. Try doing the following:

```
// On the class level
boolean drawImage = false;

// When setting the listener
bplay.addListener( new ClickListener(){
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
        drawImage = true;
    }
});

// In the render method
if (drawImage) {
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw( splash, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 
    Gdx.graphics.getHeight() );
    batch.end();
    drawImage = false;
}
```

Comment: No luck, added and no problem with the code but when i touch the imageButton it still does not do anything.

Comment: @Neill are you sure listener gets called? Try logging something in it.

Comment: Hi, I did and still no luck.

Comment: if(drawplay==true) {
             batch.begin();
             batch.draw( splash, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() );
             batch.end();
             drawplay=true;
             Gdx.app.log( "Yess","yess" );
         }
       };

Comment: @Neill Does that log the yess message? If it doesn't, then does it work if you put it in the listener?

Comment: Can i have your email adress and we can communicate via email. As that also does not work ive tried putting the listener everywhere.

Comment: Good news, i figured it out. I just needed to add multiple processors. Thanks so much!!! When creating a game where i need to pick up collisions. Can i use the drawimage and then use an if statement to see if the images overlap ? As well how can i set up a new activity and when i click on the button it goes to the new activity etc ?

Comment: @Neillbar The first question: You should ask this on the main site, but you could google axis aligned bounding box collision to get your answer. Second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173733/call-activity-when-click-button-on-core-game-libgdx